# iphone shortdate with 4 digit year

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am sure I am just missing something.  But I have googled this for days trying to find how to show a 4 digit year when displaying an NSDate with a style of NSDateFormatterShortStyle.  Please let me know if you have a solution.  Here is the code I am using now.

```
[NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease ];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    // add label for birth
    UILabel *birthday = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 10, 100, 25)];
    birthday.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    birthday.tag = kLabelTag;
    birthday.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    birthday.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    birthday.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:p.Birth];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need four digit years, set the `dateformat:` using the exact format you'd like. The downside is you lose automatic locale formatting.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

...

birthday.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:p.Birth];
```

If you need localization then you could try modifying the date format of the short style.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease ];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

if ([[dateFormatter dateFormat] rangeOfString:@"yyyy"].location == NSNotFound) { 
    NSString *fourDigitYearFormat = [[dateFormatter dateFormat] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"yy" withString:@"yyyy"]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:fourDigitYearFormat];             
}
```

*Updated with Bugfix from Max Macleod*

Comment: to localise, add the line dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];

Comment: actually, you will also need a check in case the locale specific format is already yyyy, e.g.     if ([formatString rangeOfString:@"yyyy"].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *fourDigitYearFormat = [[dateFormatter dateFormat] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"yy" withString:@"yyyy"];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:fourDigitYearFormat];
    }

Answer (score 12):

Just in case that someone stumbles in here as I did 'cos I needed such a thing with a 2 digit year in a localized date format and this is a really old question, here is my solution:

```
NSLocale*           curLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString*           dateFmt   = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate: @"ddMMyyyy"
                                                                options: 0
                                                                 locale: curLocale];
NSDateFormatter*    formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
                    [formatter setDateFormat:dateFmt];
NSString*           retText = [formatter stringFromDate:refDate];

return retText;
```

Maybe someone could use it sometime...

Comment: fantastic! I've always struggled with various other solutions and this hit the core. Thanks, mate. Keep the good work rolling.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but because I was trying to do what Dave wanted and couldn't and because none of the given answers were correct, here is the solution (in case anyone ever want's the same thing):

```
NSString *FormatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:FormatString];
//Parse date here with the formater (like [formatter stringFromDate:date])
[formatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

> kCFDateFormatterShortStyle
>   Specifies a short style, typically numeric only, such as “11/23/37” or “3:30pm”.
>
> Available in Mac OS X v10.3 and later.
>
> Declared in CFDateFormatter.h.

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDateFormatterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCFDateFormatterShortStyle)

NSDateFormatterShortStyle doesn't appear to give you 4 digit years.

Comment: this is kind of my point.  there is no format that is month/day/year that gives 4 digit years.  if i put in a format, i lose localization.  this is my frustration.

Comment: Actually it's locale-dependent: Denmark is one that gives you 4 digit years in short format. It's a great test case because it doesn't use ':' in times.